# Is it possible to hide a portion of a standard header (in C)?

Tags: c

I want to do something that seems impossible.

I want to write 3 files: **main.c**, **foo.h**, **foo.c**.
The idea is to define a struct in **foo.h** or **foo.c** in such a way that its members are visible in **main.c**. One of the struct members have type `FILE` as defined in the standard header `<stdio.h>`. But the functions and macros of `<stdio.h>` have to keep not visible inside the file **main.c**.

The solution would have to be compliant with standard C (C99 and/or C11) and portable.
Is that possible?

The header **foo.h** is #included in both, **main.c** and **foo.c**.
The standard header `<stdio.h>` is #included only in **foo.c**, but not in **main.c**.

I want to declare a `struct` as follows:

```
struct myfile_s {
   FILE *F;
   char *filename;
   char buff[100];
} myfile;
```

For what follows, only the member `FILE *F` is important.
The struct `myfile` will be initialized and modified by functions appearing in **foo.c**.
The intent is to do file operations on `myfile` through `extern` functions declared in **foo.h**, which in turn has to be defined in **foo.c**.

The file operations involve standard functions of `<stdio.h>`, but these functions have to be hidden in the file **main.c**.
However, I want to directly access, from **main.c**, to the members of `myfile`.
This would imply that the definition of `struct myfile_s` has to be done in **foo.h** (that is, it cannot be "delayed" with the trick of using incomplete struct declarations, like `struct myfile_s ;`).

In short, I would want that the type `FILE` be visible in **main.c** and/or **foo.h**, but the rest of `<stdio.h>` declarations keep hidden for them.

Another restriction: the idea of directly copying "at hand" the definition of `FILE` provided by `<stdio.h>` would not be desirable, because the code would have to be portable.

My first try was hidding the `struct myfile` by writting it inside of **foo.c**.
The code was:

**foo.h**

```
struct myfile_s;

struct myfile_s myfile;

extern void startfile(struct myfile *f);
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

struct myfile_s {
   FILE *F;
   char *filename;
   char buff[100];
} myfile;

void startfile(struct myfile *f) 
{
    // Do some stuff...
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void) 
{
   myfile.F = NULL;  // This kind of access bring error, but I want to do it anyway!!
   startfile(&myfile);
   return 0;
}
```

The delayed `struct myfile_s` declaration avoids the need to include `<stdio.h>` in **foo.h**, so the header works fine, but the struct type remains incomplete, so the access to `myfile.F` cannot be done in **main.c**.

So:  **How can I access to myfile.F?**

I tried another way that, of course, gives error too:

**foo.h**

```
struct myfile_s {
   FILE *F;
   char *filename;
   char buff[100];
} myfile;

extern void startfile(struct myfile *f);
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void startfile(struct myfile *f) 
{
    // Do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to work with two different headers? a internal headerfile and a external? the external just knows void pointer(or in your case the FILE pointer part of the structure) and internal you cast those void pointers to your types so the one with the internal headerfile knows the parts ou want to keep internal and the external header jsut shows what you want to give out.

Comment: Did you tried including `<stdio.h>` in `foo.h` i.e. where you define your struct ... I prefer to declare it in the header

Comment: What didn't work with the second approach? It looks mostly on the right track.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: because the type `FILE` is defined in `<stdio.h> `, which is included in `foo.c` but not in `foo.h`. The idea is that the functions of `<stdio.h>` has to be not visible in the file `main.c`.

Comment: Add a `#define FILE void` to your main. Might help (but is a bit of a hack, admitted). This of course before including foo.h

Comment: The real question is why your `main.c` can't include `<stdio.h>`. Seems like in your effort to be standards conformant, your `main.c` is not... I can't see another reason why else you would have this ridiculous puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct myfile_s {
   void *pPrivateThings; // This could be the FILE* or another private structure
   char *filename;
   char buff[100];
} myfile;
```

I would allocate another private structure on creation:

```
struct myprivatefile_s {
    FILE *F;
    // You could add other fields here that are not public
} myprivatefile;

myprivatefile *privateThings = malloc(sizeof(myprivatefile));
myfile.pPrivateThings = privateThings;
privateThings->F = fopen();
```

That way you can keep on adding things that aren't required to be visible (i.e. private) to your heart's content.

Comment: Looks like the pimpl C++ idiom. Just, I'd add you can just declare `struct myprivatefile_s;` without defining it in the "public" header, and use the type in the pointer instead of `void*`.

Comment: You are using `myfile` as a "type", but it is a variable of type `struct myfile_s`. However this is a minor error. I've tried to use void* pointers yet, which brings access to myfile.F, but now the problem is that the "actual" type `FILE` is not "pure" (it's not the real one). However, you have given a good answer, as based on the way I have performed the question. It's not what I am looking for, but your answer is my favorite one, since you have give me several ideas.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error.  Have corrected it and shown how to use the file pointer with it.

Answer (score 6):

That's all needlessly complicated, isn't it?

It looks as if you don't really know what you want. Why do you want to have a single instance of `myfile` in `foo.h`? Why do you want to set `myfile.F` explicitly in `main`? Why not write a function like `myfile_init` for that in `foo.c`, which has full access?

I'd do a typedef of an opaque struct in `foo.h`, define the stuff and implement constructor and accessor functions in `foo.h` and then create an instance of `myfile` in `main.c`:

**foo.h**

```
typedef struct Myfile Myfile;

Myfile *myfile_open(const char *filename);
myfile_process(Myfile *f, ...);
int myfile_close(Myfile *f);
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Myfile {
    FILE *f;
    ...
};

// implement myfile_xxx functions
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    Myfile *f = myfile_open("rhubarb.txt");

    if (f == NULL) exit(1);
    myfile_process(f, ...);
    myfile_close(f);

    return 0;
}
```

No need to partially include other headers. By moving initialisation to `myfile_open`, everything is neatly encapsulated in `foo.c`. The main program sees only handles. Quite like the standard `FILE *` handles, really.